# fonts (class, styles) for new academic journal

Tags: fonts, bibtex, document-classes

I am involved with starting a new academic economics and finance journal. Thus, the world is our oyster---we can choose whatever looks we want to choose. Since I have a role, LaTeX is going to be our typesetting system.

Now, I want my authors to be able to install the latest TexLive and be able to format the article themselves, although we will do this for many of them. This means that I do not want any fonts or other required inputs that are proprietary, and that require anything unusual. It should work out of the box.

For fonts, I need a full complement of math with the text. `cmr` is out. Even though it is now scalable, it just has acquired too much of a "texy working paper" look at this point.  I am thinking `mathptmx`. I also like the idea of sticking to one font for headings and text, if only because this won't create a garish amateurish look, and I can see myself committing a *faux pas* if I had to mix fonts. TUG `lucida` is out, not because it requires a purchase, but because it requires an installation. Would the TeX Gyre fonts offer some good suitable alternative to `mathptmx`? Again, I need something fairly complete.

What is considered to be the most sane BiBTeX `bst` format?  (we use `harvard.sty` in economics.)

The publisher itself is a small boutique. They use a style file obvious in http://www.qjps.com/prod.aspx?product=QJPS&vol=1&nr=1. Any critiques of this style would be welcome, too.

Any other recommendations are appreciated, too. (yes, I did an extensive search of this forum before I posted and read a couple of related posts.)

Comment: If your authors might be working on university computers, these could well have an older version of TeXlive or MikTeX on them. So I'd advise against using any cutting-edge TL2011-only packages...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This site works best if you ask one clearly defined question at a time. You might want to split up your question into several, like one for font recommendation and one for bst format recommendation.

Comment: Further to @N.N.'s comment, this question is mainly asking for opinions about things, which isn't quite the nature of the Stackexchange model, which is designed to yield questions with answers that can be taken to be definitive relative to the question.

Comment: re a bib format, look into the `natbib' package; it implements many styles including harvard, and is quite reliable and flexible.

Comment: @Ivo: The tex-gyre fonts closest to `Times Roman` and `Helvetica` are called `tgtermes` and `tgheros`, respectively. In your journal's style file, be sure to load hyperref, sideways, cleveref, booktabs, and siunitx packages (the latter mostly for its advanced column formatting capabilities).